# How to pass input text with commas through laravel form?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pass string input with commas through laravel form text field. You can provide multiple numbers separated by commas, the application will handle imploding into array.

The issue is that laravel (or web browser) by default will change comma to '%2C'. I know it's a safety feature, but this is not too big concern in case of this application.

Is there a way to disable this?

Already tried to use {!! !!} instead of standard {{ }}

```
{{ Form::text('number', null) }}
```

Comment: I don't know laravel but are they commas when you view it in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using POST method in form tag  instead of GET method.
It will not show field value in URL.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a bit. I thought my code is not working properly with url parameter. Actually I was wrong, even though it changed comma in the url it still passed proper paramater value to application.